# Refreshing vue.js app without hard reloading

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a Vue.js todo list CRUD app based on a tutorial posted on Medium: (part 1) https://medium.com/@magyarn/vuefire-crud-todo-list-app-part-1-e069c46b50c6, (part 2) https://medium.com/@magyarn/vuefire-crud-todo-list-app-part-2-8bd61ae0d066

I built the app in it's entirety and was successful in connecting it to a Firestore database. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to render the list items on the DOM once they have been added to the database. In other words, I have to click the browser refresh button to see the list items on the screen after they have been added to the database. To resolve this, I added window.location.reload to each method to automatically trigger a page reload whenever I click add, edit, or delete, but this doesn't seem like a good long-term solution. Here is an example:

```
    addTodo() {
      todosCollection.add({
        text: this.newTodo,
        completed: false,
        id: this.todos.length,
        createdAt: new Date()
      })
      .then(() => {
        window.location.reload()
      })
```

```
   deleteTodo(todo) {
      todosCollection.doc(todo.id).delete()
      .then(() => {
        window.location.reload()
      })
    },
```

I also added a special hook in order to retrieve the items in the database and render them to the DOM after manually refreshing:

```
methods: {
...
},
created(){
    todosCollection.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let newTodo = doc.data()
        newTodo.id = doc.id
        this.todos.push(newTodo)
      })
    })
  }
```

My question is what is the best way to handle refreshing without reloading for this kind of single page Vue.js app? Thanks!

Comment: You should use the realtime update function of Firebase. How do you get list of `todos` at the moment?

Comment: Hi @ittus, I used a "created()" hook with a get method to retrieve the list items in the database and then push them into the "todos" array. This seems to work in getting the list, but I still have to hit click the refresh button in the browser to render content onto the screen. I just updated my post with the created hook.

Comment: These are typically the scenarios where you use a `vuex` store to handle the operations of a collection. It helps with ensuring all the components of your app have the updated data at any given point of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few ways to do it:

**Method 1:**
Using Vuefire binding

Remove your getting list in created and add following code to your component:

```
  firestore() {
    return {
      todos: todosCollection.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    }
  },
```

[Vuefire document](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/tree/master/packages/vuefire#firestore-option)

**Method 2:**
Update your list manually. First, separate getting data to a method and call it in `created` hook and after each actions

```
created() {
  this.getData()  
},
methods: {
  getData() {
    const todos = []
    todosCollection.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let newTodo = doc.data()
        newTodo.id = doc.id
        todos.push(newTodo)
      })
      this.todos = todos
    })
  },
  addTodo() {
      todosCollection.add({
        text: this.newTodo,
        completed: false,
        id: this.todos.length,
        createdAt: new Date()
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.getData()
      })
  },
  deleteTodo(todo) {
    todosCollection.doc(todo.id).delete()
    .then(() => {
      this.getData()
    })
  },
}
```